# How to render a circle with as few vertices as possible?

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to decide how many vertices I need to have to make my circle look as smooth as possible.

Here is an example of two circles, both having 24 vertices:
[image]

As you see, the bigger the circle becomes, the more vertices I need to hide the straight lines.

At first I thought that the minimum length of one line on the edge should be 6px, but that approach failed when I increased the circle size: I got way too many vertices. I also thought about calculating the angles, but I quickly realised that angles doesn't differ on different sized circles. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243668/when-drawing-an-ellipse-or-circle-with-opengl-how-many-vertices-should-we-use) answer, but I don't have a clue how to convert it into code (and some weird stuff there: `th` uses itself for calculating itself), and I think it doesn't even work, since the author is using the angle from one slice to the middle of circle, which doesn't change if the circle gets larger.

Then I realised that maybe the solution is to check the angle between two vertices at the edges, in this way:

[image]

As you see, the fewer vertices, the bigger the lengths are for those triangles. So this has to be the answer, I just don't know how to calculate the number of vertices by using this information.

Comment: Your diagrams suggest that you are doing something very strange indeed.  You seem to be calculating the positions of the 'radial' lines from a point on the edge of the circle; most of us would use lines from the centre of the circle.  That may account for the trouble you are having understanding the answer you reference. Do you want to draw the 'radial' lines, or only the circumference of the circle ?

Comment: What are you using as for your render engine? For instance is it OpenGL or GDI or GDI+? In other words, how can you count the number of pixels needed to draw a line?

Comment: This may be way to simple approach, but if you did calculations on anything I would probably use the length of the line @ 90 deg. that's the diameter which will change. You would still be using trial and error to establish the relationship.

Comment: @MehranZiadloo, I will render in 2d, so its easy to count the pixels. opengl or not, it doesnt matter since i may be using non-opengl rendering at any time. the solution should work at anywhere.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, what or how i draw has nothing to do with this question, i just need to calculate how many points (vertices) does the circle need for its edges so it looks very round.

Comment: Have you achieved an acceptable amount of verts on the big one. The small has 24 and looks good, but what does it take to make the big one look good. And what is the ratio of their sizes?

Comment: @RobertoWilko, i thought of that: manually checking each size, and then figuring out how the ratio could be calculated. I think the bigger one needs 48 vertices? so ratio would be 2.5 or something. (bigger circle is 5x bigger but needs twice as many vertices (i think)).

Comment: "I got way too many vertices" - how many is too many? Isn't the result of this going to be that larger circles *do* have many more verticies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer you link to actually implements exactly the idea you propose at the end of your question.

The decisive formula that you need from that answer is this one:

```
th = arccos(2 * (1 - e / r)^2 - 1)
```

This tells you the angle between two vertices, where `r` is the radius of the circle and `e` is the maximum error you're willing to tolerate, i.e. the maximum deviation of your polygon from the circle -- this is the error marked in your diagram. For example, you might choose to set `e` to 0.5 of a pixel.

Because `th` is measured in radians, and 360 degrees (a full circle) is equal to `2*pi` in radians, the number of vertices you need is

```
num_vertices = ceil(2*pi/th)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to draw the polygon triangles from the center of the circle, the formula for the required number of sides is:

`sides = PI / arccos(1 - error / radius)`

where `error` is the maximum deviation of polygon from the circle, in pixels and `radius` is also expressed in pixels.

Error `0.33` seems to produce results indistinguishable from an ideal circle. Circles drawn at error `0.5`, on close inspection still show some subtly visible angles between sides, especially visible in small circles.

This function obviously breaks down when radius is much smaller than error, and may produce `NaN` values. You may want to use a special case (for example draw 3 sides) in this situation.

The graph below shows number of sides obtained from the function, with error set to `0.33`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using OpenGL or DirectX you can significantly decrease the number of vertices by using a [triangle fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_fan) structure.

As for the problem of the amount of vertices, I would imagine the number of vertices required for a smooth circle to scale with the circumference. This scales with r, so I would advice to find a good factor `A` such that:

`#vertices = A * r`

Comment: The relationship is not linear, so no suitable factor A exists that covers a wide range of circle sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The angles are the same in the two cases of 24 vertices.

But with larger circle, the human eye is able to better see the individual straight lines.

So you need some heuristic that takes into account

- the angle between two consecutive line segments in the curve, and
- the size, and possibly
- the scaling for display.

The third point is difficult since one does not in general know the size at which some graphic will be displayed. E.g., an SVG format picture can be displayed at any size. The most general solution, I think, is to have direct support for various figures (Bezier lines, circles, etc.) in the renderer, and then define the figure with a few parameters instead of as a sequence of points. Or, define it in terms of some figure that the renderer supports, e.g. as a sequence of connected Bezier curves. That way, the renderer can add the necessary number of points to make it look smooth and nice.

However, I guess that you're not creating a renderer, so then perhaps only the first two points above are relevant.