# Do Javascript's ctx.arc method calculate the vertices relative to pixel size and radius?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, rendering

In Javascript's Canvas, you can easily draw a circle using the ctx.arc method, I wonder, do the arc function calculate the number of vertices needed to draw a circle for the best performance and graphics?

In some cases (using Chrome) you can see that it's a regular polygon and not a "circle".

The formula for the radians between each vertex is:

```
th = arccos(2 * (1 - e / r)^2 - 1)
```

where e is the pixel size

as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774038/how-to-render-a-circle-with-as-few-vertices-as-possible) question.

So, finally, should I use the existing function or make my own using the formula for the best performance and graphics?

Comment: I think, for you, is better to use ctx.arc instead of using your own written function for rendering arc. However, if you want to render regular polygon you can write your own function. Of course for best performance you would like to use native functions.

Answer (score -1):

**Best graphic appearance:**

The browser does automatic anti-aliasing and your manually calculated version would not--so your circle would visually look much more "jaggy".

**Performance:**

I suspect browsers have optimized context.arc, but you could always run a performance test:

http://jsperf.com/